# How to open, jump to a page, change page size (basic read only operations of PDF)

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am very beginner in this iText. I just want to know how to do basic things with PDF from Java.

- How to open a PDF page so that the PDF file is opened in front of me?
- How to jump to a page (by page number) so that I see seeked page in front of me?
- How to change page size so that I see page size changed in front of me?

I know these things can be done using mouse and keyboard, but I just want to make a program that open PDF files according to parameters.

When I do search about iText, I just found topics that tackle creation/modification issues.

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstood what iText is for. It's not a library for PDF rendering, you won't be able to visualize a PDF file with iText.

As for your issue, most of the PDF viewers ([Adobe Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf), [Foxit Reader](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/commandlineswitches.php#Foxit)) accept parameters to achieve (partly) what you want.

It's just a matter of finding the proper reader. Remember that seeking advices about libraries, applications, frameworks is considered off-topic on StackOverflow, so your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Thanks. I can open PDF using Java (http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-in-java/). But I can't specify parameters for PDF file. So in general, if there is a way to achieve my question without **iText**, it is preferable.